# SEScripts - A Bunch of Scripts

Tags: script, chrome-extensions

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

The [SEScripts](https://github.com/FEichinger/sescripts) Chrome Extension adds various userscripts all around Stack Exchange, combined in a simple suite.

#### Contents

**SECU - Chat**

*Stack Exchange Chat Utilities* adds a variety of extensions to the StackExchange chat:

The Buttons option adds custom buttons to the input area, allowing for easy access to your everyday non-standard inputs and old quotes. With the Alerts option allows setting a list of alert words that, when posted to chat, are highlit and trigger chat's iconic ping sound. The newly-added Clear option can be used to wipe the visible transcript on the fly - to remove nasty pictures, or simply to get some calming whitespace.

**SEPU - Posts**

*Stack Exchange Post Utilities* simply adds a link to the post tools that goes straight to the question's timeline. On top of that, it also makes a revision link visible on all posts.

**SEEU - Election**

*Stack Exchange Election Utilities* fixes this pesky problem with the missing comment links on the election pages. The timestamp now links right to the correct comment.

#### License

This extension is released under the MIT License.

#### Download

- [**Complete Chrome Extension** (CRX)](https://github.com/FEichinger/sescripts/raw/master/downloads/chrome-sescripts.crx)
- [Git master branch ZIP](https://github.com/FEichinger/sescripts/archive/master.zip)

#### Platform

The extension itself is built for Chrome, <del>while the individual scripts are compatible with most other UserScript agents.</del> **Currently, there is no cross-browser variant available, as the new storage mechanism is focused on Chrome!**

### Contact

For feedback on *SEScripts*, refer to the [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/FEichinger/sescripts/issues).

### Code

JavaScript. Pure and simple JavaScript. No jQuery, just JavaScript. See the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/FEichinger/sescripts) for more details.